# How can we prove in general that C is not a linear mapping (homogeneous)?

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the linear mappings $B$ and $C$ defined like this: $B: p \to Bp$ and $C: p \to Cp$. Is there a way to show that the mappings $B: p \to  Bp$ where $(Bp)(x) = p (p(x))$, $\forall$ $x \in R$ and $C: p \to  Cp$ where $(Cp)(x) = (p(x))^2$, $\forall x \in R$ IN GENERAL are not homogoneous? I have proved that with a counterexample but I am curious about how it is done on a general example. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you state what $B$, $C$ and $p$ are?

Comment: I think you mean the mappings $p\to Bp$ and $p\to Cp$. If so, please edit your question. Anyway, all you need to prove something is not homogeneous is an example, and it's likely to be a different example for every non-homogeneous map.

Comment: $B$ and $C$ are mappings from $R[x] \to R[x]$, and p is a polynomial from $R[x]$.

Comment: The notation $B\to Bp$ is used when $B$ is the argument and gets taken to $Bp$. It's not used when $B$ is a mapping that takes $p$ to $Bp$. For that, you might write $B:p\to Bp$. Similarly for $C$. *Please* edit your question so it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Now it is written as it should be.

Comment: You write that you have linear mappings $B$ and $C$, but the mappings $B$ and $C$ that you define are (as you know) not linear, so the question still needs editing. Anyway, the general way to show that $B$ is not homogeneous is to find a scalar $\alpha$ and a vector $p$ such that $B(\alpha p)\ne\alpha B(p)$. Beyond that, I don't think there's much to be said. How you find that $\alpha$ and that $p$ is going to depend on $B$. There's no general formula for them.